# Tracking Site Search - Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am attempting to track site searches in Google Analytics.  My Profile Settings are set to "Do Track Site Search."

When searching on the site, the URL string is output as: `www.website.com/Search.aspx?searchtext=keyword&searchmode=AnyWord`.  The Search Mode is actually a drop down box, and you can select "Any Word," "Exact Phrase," or "All Words."  I've set `searchtext=` to be my query parameter and `searchmode=` to be a category parameter within the GA interface.  I have not seen any data get recorded yet though.

My understanding from reading the GA Help Section is that the GA tracking code on the site doesn't need to be manipulated in any way.  Is that incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seems that you are including the equal sign as part of the query parameter when in fact it shouldn't Just use "searchtext" and "searchmode", no quotes.

eg:

[image: SiteSearch Example]

Comment: Thank you, Eduardo.  I'll see if that works.  When reading the set up guide in the help section it seemed as though they said to include the equal sign, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: @eduardo, sorry for opening up an old post. In my case, I have two query parameters. One is "activity" and the other is "destination". If I provide these two as comma separated, how would Google count the metrics?
For e.g. ?activity=A&destination=B, would it count one for each or pick just one query parameter?